# How to include custom splash screen in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, splash-screen

I have made the composable function for splash screen as below

`Logo.kt`

```
private lateinit var customTypeFace: Typeface

@Composable
fun Logo(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    val gradient = Brush.verticalGradient(
        colors = listOf(
            Color(0xFF0A1478),
            Color(0xFFBEC8FF)
        )
    )
    val context = LocalContext.current

    Canvas(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(gradient)
    ) {
        val padding = 20
        val path = Path().apply {
            moveTo(x = padding.toFloat() * 6, y = center.y)
            lineTo(x = size.width - padding * 6, y = center.y)
        }
        customTypeFace = context.resources.getFont(R.font.marckscript_regular)

        /**
         * For drawing the text we dont have the such method called [drawText].
         * To overcome this we can use [nativeCanvas].
         */
        this.drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas.apply {

            drawTextOnPath(
                "BAE Calling App",
                path.asAndroidPath(),
                0f,
                0f,
                Paint().apply {
                    this.color = android.graphics.Color.WHITE
                    this.textSize = 120f
                    this.textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
                    this.typeface = customTypeFace
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun LogoPreview() {
    BaeCallingAppTheme {
        Logo()
    }
}
```

Now I want to start `Logo.kt` as a splash screen. My splash screen setup is as below

`MainActivity.kt`

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var splashViewModel: SplashViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        installSplashScreen().let {
            it.setKeepOnScreenCondition {
                splashViewModel.isLoading.value.not()
            }
            setContent {
                BaeCallingAppTheme {
                    val screen by splashViewModel.startDestination
                    setUpNavController(
                        controller = rememberNavController(),
                        startDestination = screen
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`themes.xml` for splash screen.

```
<style name="Theme.CustomSplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">600</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.BaeCallingApp</item>
</style>
```

I know if I include the icon in `themes.xml` the icon will launch as the splash screen, but instead of any icon I want to launch `Logo.kt` file as my splash screen. I am using `Navigation Compose` library as well to navigate between the screens.

```
Note -> One way to achieve this is to have delay of 5 sec before launching the home screen (Possible via LaunchedEffect and navigation) but this leds to an issue of white screen for some seconds before launching the splash screen which I don't want it.
```

Is there any way to achieve it?